# Trouble using regex patterns any Python to find content in a document

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a list of regex expressions that I want to find in certain docs.

```
x = ['\bin\sapp\sdata\b','\bin\sapp\sdata\b','\benough\sdata\b']
```

The patterns repeat themselves so I converted them to a set (see the first and second values in the list)

```
y = set(x)
```

When I try to find them in a specific doc it doesn't find them since it doesn't take them as a repr version:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

results = list()
doc = 'they wanted in app data and we did not provide it'
for value in y:
    results.append(re.findall(pattern = value,string=doc))
results = list(filter(None, results))
results
```

How do I overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your actual code that definitively proves your assertion about this not being a repr.

Comment: Sure. ```x = ['\bin\sapp\sdata\b']```
```y = set(x)```
```print(y)```
You can see that when printed, you have two backslashes
this interferes later on when I try to tokenize it as a dictionary for TF-ITF

Comment: Yeah, because when you print a `set`, you get the repr of its contents. Try `print(y.pop())`…

Comment: nevertheless, when I try to find it in a doc it can't be found due to this format:
```results = list()
#doc = df_l.iloc[647,1]
doc = 'they wanted in app data and we did not provide i'
for value in y:
    results.append(re.findall(pattern = value,string=doc))
results = list(filter(None, results))
results```

Comment: [Edit] your question to be about that actual problem with a reproducible example. This is unreadable and unanswerable in a comment thread.

Comment: Done. I still don't see a reason to penalize me...

Comment: Given that sample, you don't have the string `'\bin\sapp\sdata\b'`, you have the string `'\x08in\\sapp\\sdata\x08'`, which is why nothing matches. Try with `r'\bin\sapp\sdata\b'`…?

Comment: The problem is that I have thousands of these and I can't add them manually.

Comment: Where do "they" come from? Have you typed them like this—as shown—into your source code? Then you already messed up, because `'\b'` is not "\b", it's `'\x08'`. Or do "they" come from elsewhere where that is actually not relevant?

Comment: Unfortunately, I typed them in the source code...
How do I add them then so that it will be considered as ``` \b```?

Comment: By using a *raw string*: `r'\b'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225965/discussion-between-nimi1234-and-deceze).

Comment: The problem was with the python 3.7 version. The error I got was "bad escape \l at position 0"
Once I changed the re to regex it worked perfectly fine, even with the "messed up coding"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the python 3.7 version. The error I got was "bad escape \l at position 0" Once I changed the re to regex it worked perfectly fine, even with the "messed up coding